# Programmatically display the globe view on iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, dictionary, zooming, mapkit

The latest iOS Maps app allows you to zoom out to see a 3D view of the earth (complete with lighting relevant to the position of the sun) if you are in satellite or hybrid modes.

Does anyone know if we can achieve this programatically in our own apps without resorting to some 3rd party solution?

Comment: From a quick glance at the Map Kit documentation, it looks like you would create an `MKMapView` instance and assign a `MKMapCamera` to the view's `camera` property. Have you tried this?

Comment: From what I tried with this it seems more for showing street view level objects in 3d, not the whole globe .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MapKit doesn't do this yet. The globe view just debuted in iOS 7, so it might come in the future. You need to go third party.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks for the confirmation. I ended up going for WhirlyGlobe (which is awesome by the way).